# programmatically using a value converter in C# in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a C# Silverlight application. In this application I have defined a value converter that I am using in the XAML. I have run into a situation where I need to programmatically use this value converter in my code behind. My question is, how do I do that? In XAML, I am using my value converter as follows:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=FirstName, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}, ConverterParameter=NotSet}" />
```

How do I use this converter in my code-behind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

If you just want to call the converter explicitly in the code behind, just use the converter class just like any other class and call its Convert() methos with appropriate parameters

```
YourConverter conv = new YourConverter();
conv.Convert(...)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I personally add a static method to the converter like so:

```
public static object Convert(object value)
{
    return new MyConverter().Convert(value, null, null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

You can then use this in code like so:

```
MyConverter.Convert(valueToConvert);
```

You can even change the return type and cast the result before returning to make usage easier.

Comment: I like this answer as it simplifies the calling, no newing, and no unneeded parameters